# Two Strong name key's handling in C# project through

Tags: c#, strongname, snk

I have arround 40 project in single solution(VS2010). Now I have created one Strong Name Key(SNK) and added each project and refered SNK file.

Now, my requirement is , Two SNK file I have to create and keep it one place(root folder). That file I have to refer dynamically or only one place modification, it should refelect all 40 projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can Easyly refer to a relative path for the .snk key in your .config files as described in the following page
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/04/24/582278.aspx
BR